# curl_exec() не выводит данные при парсинге связкой PHP и cURL

Tags: php, curl, парсер

Осваиваю cURL, не получается получить содержимое:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://ya.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$text = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match( '/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/is' , $text , $p_content );
echo $p_content[0];
?>
```

Ссылка заменена, на запрашиваемой странице есть как минимум один абзац.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас парсер работает, только выводит в консоль, чтобы функция `curl_exec()` делала своё дело — возвращала значение в скрипт (и потом только `echo`), а не 
выводила содержимое переменной на экран, допишите:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1');
```